# Xamarin iOS Your app is using a compiler option that requires xamarin.ios Business edition

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Since downloading the latest version of Xamarin Studio 5.9 I cannot compile my ioS application. I get the error message -

Your app is using a compiler option that requires xamarin.ios Business edition or higher
Your app is using the compiler option --profiling.

I have not chosen the profiler option but cannot find a way to turn it off.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some investigation, I found out that the update to the latest version of Xamarin Studio had caused a change to the settings in the .csproj file. Opening the file and searching the xml I found two nodes called MtouchProfiling with the value set to true. I changed the values to false and built again, voila, working!

Comment: Worked for me.. The profiling in the Debugging options was disabled already for me, so the option blow did not work!

Answer (score 1):

To disable profiling go to Project options / iOS Build and in Debugging Options uncheck Enable profiling.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Profiling was off but Xamarin thought is was on.
I had to disable Debugging, rebuild the Solution after a clean all, re-enable debugging (with Profiling turned off)